# pip install WakaDump: SyntaxError: invalid syntax at except TypeError, e

Tags: python, pip, wakatime

While install [wakadump](https://github.com/wakatime/wakadump) over Windows, I get following error

```
$ pip install wakadump
Collecting wakadump
  Using cached wakadump-2.0.1.tar.gz
Collecting click==4.0 (from wakadump)
  Using cached click-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keen==0.3.3 (from wakadump)
  Using cached keen-0.3.3.tar.gz
Collecting pytz==2015.4 (from wakadump)
  Using cached pytz-2015.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplejson==3.6.5 (from wakadump)
  Using cached simplejson-3.6.5.tar.gz
Collecting unicodecsv==0.9.4 (from wakadump)
  Using cached unicodecsv-0.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\!USERNAME!\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zqck6wkt\unicodecsv\set                                                                                                                                  up.py", line 5, in <module>
        version = __import__('unicodecsv').__version__
      File "C:\Users\!USERNAME!\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zqck6wkt\unicodecsv\uni                                                                                                                                  codecsv\__init__.py", line 49
        except TypeError, e:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sakhar\A                                                                                                                                  ppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zqck6wkt\unicodecsv
```

I rechecked and I have setup tools installed to latest version and also PIP is upgraded to latest version.

I tried updating everything and also restarted the system to make sure things get reflected but no luck.

Comment: your traceback seems to be cutoff. It should be wider than what you copied in your code block. Can you double-check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wakadump`has been created incompatible (old) Python version and does not support the modern Python version you have installed.

Python 3.x uses syntax `except TypeError as e` (new) not `except TypeError, e` (old).

`wakadump` must be upgraded to support new Python versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue, this issue is now fixed - https://github.com/wakatime/wakadump/issues/5